# No sound on Ubuntu 18.04. Dummy output

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound, lenovo, soundcard

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it appears that the sound drivers I have do not work properly (I think). So when I open the sound settings window, I can see only "Dummy output" for output devices. My internal microphone isn't recognized as well (no input devices).

I'm using Lenovo ThinkBook 13s
Here are some outputs:

```
$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_nhlt         20480  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec         131072  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_core           90112  11 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_pcm               102400  10 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                    86016  12 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02c8]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3816]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
```

```
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

Does anyone know a solution that could work? Or at least to point my out what the issue is...

**UPDATE:**
output from dmesg:

```
skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: Unsupported HDAudio/iDisp configuration found
skl_hda_dsp_generic: probe of skl_hda_dsp_generic failed with error -22
```

Comment: Is there any related error in your kernel log?

Comment: @dragosht This is the only thing that looked relevant in dmesg
[    9.947177] skl_hda_dsp_generic: probe of skl_hda_dsp_generic failed with error -22
Any suggestions what else I could check?

Comment: @dragosht I also updated the question

Comment: After more digging [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update) solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem here. Running Ubuntu 18.04.4 on an Acer Swift 5 (SF514-54T). After an update, I lost all sound and got a "dummy output" in place of the soundcard.

It seems that the problem was the update to Ubuntu kernel 5.3.0-42-generic which has been recently reported as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe/+bug/1868010).

Reverting to the previous kernel 5.3.0-40-generic should solve the problem.

To see what version kernel you are running type in the terminal:

```
uname -r
```

You can boot to the previous kernel by selecting the relevant option in the grub2 boot loader. Once in the grub2 menu, select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and then choose "5.3.0-40-generic".

If the grub2 menu does not appear, press ESC or (left) SHIFT while booting.

If pressing these keys does not work to bring up the grub2 menu, you need to manually edit the boot loader settings. This can be done by e.g. tweaking the grub.cfg file using a text editor (in this case gedit):

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Search for "timeout" and change the following to:

```
set timeout_style=menu
set timeout=10
```

and save the grub.cfg file. Next time you boot, the grub2 menu should appear.

I reckon that there must be more elegant solutions until the bug is fixed but, for the moment, this did the trick for me. Let me know if this solution worked for you!

Comment: thanks, Kostas! worked for me: Lenovo Thinkpad X1 carbon 7th gen.