# Ubuntu 18.04 audio disappeared after update

Tags: 18.04, sound, thinkpad

I've been using Ubuntu 18.04 on my Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th gen for some time now with the audio working just fine, but after running some updates yesterday it seems like the audio card has stopped working when I rebooted this morning, could this be related to each other?

dmsg output:

```
[   32.624585] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: Unsupported HDAudio/iDisp configuration found
[   32.624590] skl_hda_dsp_generic: probe of skl_hda_dsp_generic failed with error -22
```

output from /var/log/apt/history.log:

```
Start-Date: 2020-03-17  09:30:06
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.214'
Install: linux-image-5.3.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.3.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.3.0-42:amd64 (5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.3.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64 (1.10.6-2ubuntu1.2, 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-88.88, 4.15.0-91.92), linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.3.0.40.97, 5.3.0.42.99), libnm0:amd64 (1.10.6-2ubuntu1.2, 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4), network-manager:amd64 (1.10.6-2ubuntu1.2, 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4), linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.3.0.40.97, 5.3.0.42.99), linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.3.0.40.97, 5.3.0.42.99), linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.3.0.40.97, 5.3.0.42.99), network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu:amd64 (1.10.6-2ubuntu1.2, 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4), code:amd64 (1.42.1-1581432938, 1.43.0-1583783132), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.173.15, 1.173.16), docker-ce:amd64 (5:19.03.7~3-0~ubuntu-bionic, 5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic), docker-ce-cli:amd64 (5:19.03.7~3-0~ubuntu-bionic, 5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)
End-Date: 2020-03-17  09:31:51

Start-Date: 2020-03-18  06:58:27
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.3.0-28:amd64 (5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1), linux-headers-5.3.0-28-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-03-18  06:58:27

Start-Date: 2020-03-18  06:58:30
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-28-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-03-18  06:58:31

Start-Date: 2020-03-18  06:58:36
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-5.3.0-28-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1), linux-image-5.3.0-28-generic:amd64 (5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-03-18  06:58:40

Start-Date: 2020-03-18  06:58:48
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libcephfs2:amd64 (12.2.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.4, 12.2.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.5)
End-Date: 2020-03-18  06:58:49

Start-Date: 2020-03-18  06:58:53
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libicu60:amd64 (60.2-3ubuntu3, 60.2-3ubuntu3.1)
End-Date: 2020-03-18  06:58:55

Start-Date: 2020-03-18  06:59:01
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: librados2:amd64 (12.2.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.4, 12.2.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.5)
End-Date: 2020-03-18  06:59:02

Start-Date: 2020-03-18  06:59:08
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.11, 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.12)
End-Date: 2020-03-18  06:59:09

Start-Date: 2020-03-18  06:59:14
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.11, 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.12)
End-Date: 2020-03-18  06:59:15

Start-Date: 2020-03-18  06:59:18
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: apport:amd64 (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.11, 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.12)
End-Date: 2020-03-18  06:59:21

Start-Date: 2020-03-18  06:59:24
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.11, 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.12)
End-Date: 2020-03-18  06:59:25
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So to answer my own question. After a lot of digging I finally managed to get my audio working again. After finding this thread https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64720 I tried temporarily adding the boot parameter `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` by following this guide: [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter) to verify that it worked. It solved my problem, and I added the key permanently now, and the fix seems to persist after reboot.

Comment: Thanks, this was the correct answer for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked for me on Ubuntu 19.10 after updating today and getting no sound card detected and dummy output for sound.

Comment: Did not work for me on Ubuntu 19.10., but was able to fix it anyways. See my answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1218725/748806

Comment: Super, thanks a lot, this worked for me (also 18.04 on X1C7)! :-)))

Comment: Awesome work! This also worked on my Acer Swift 3.

So, it seems like they were trying to fix the issue of the internal microphone not working, and instead made the sound driver not work at all?

PS you can mark your own answer as the correct one, this might earn you some reputation and/or a badge ;)

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me on my Dell Vostro 7590. Audio stopped working after upgrading kernel from 5.3.0-40 to 5.3.0-42 on Xubuntu 19.04, the boot parameter fixed it.

Comment: p.s.: Did you get the mic to work on your X1C7? If yes, then it would be great if you open a thread letting us know how you did it (so far I have not managed to get the microphone running, with 18.04 on X1C7)

Comment: @Stefan unfortunately I have yet to get the microphone to work. The built-in audio jack works for using external microphones, but the internal microphone does not work at all for me.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me on a Vostro-7590. Ubuntu 18.04.4 with kernel 5.3.0-46-generic.

Comment: @Tomas: an update to my Q about mic on X1C7: After an upgrade on 20.04 steps 3-5 of this worked to get my microphone to work!
https://mathieularose.com/ubuntu-19-10-on-lenovo-thinkpad-x1-carbon-7th-gen/

Comment: @Stefan that's interesting! I recently upgraded to 20.04 myself and I'm going to try this and see if it works.

Comment: This solution worked for me previously, but then after some other changes to my audio system involving microphone, suddenly it failed. This one fixed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214154/pulseaudio-not-working-kernel-driver-broken/1214163#1214163

Answer (score 1):

I am on Ubuntu 19.10, Thinkpad X1C7 and had the same problem. Also, I was not able to shutdown anymore. I tried your own answer but it didn't help.

So I rolled back the kernel from 5.3.0.42-generic to 5.3.0.40-generic following this instruction:
[How to downgrade kernel after bad update (16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945403/how-to-downgrade-kernel-after-bad-update-16-04)

After a reboot, it worked.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is probably as different story because it's not part of the certified hardware thing. Nice that you were able to fix it.

Comment: While trying your solution on a Thinkpad X1C7, I get warned "Your are running a kernel and attempting to remove the same version". Is this warning part of the normal rolling-back workflow, or should I be suspicious about that?

Comment: I observed the warning as well and continued. It should automatically roll back to an older kernel version, if one is installed! Maybe check that you are not removing the only version you have.