# Ubuntu 18.04 - Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon sound card not recognized since firmware update

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound, lenovo, thinkpad

I recently updated firmware on my Thinkpad Carbon X1 (last gen, 7th I guess) and since (I'm not sure it is the cause of my problem, but it happens simultaneously), I only have a "dummy device" in sound configuration panel on Ubuntu 18.04.
I tried a lot of stuff suggested around the web and still, the result of `aplay -l` is always `no sound card detected`.
The output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio` is :

```
Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9dc8] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2292]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
```

Any suggestion how to fix this ?

Comment: Kernel is? `uname -a` please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all of you that answered and commented my question. While waiting for an answer here, I found someone on the web with the same problem that was advised to go and look here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061/comments/3. The two steps proposed there solved the issue :

- add `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` in the configuration file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
- add `blacklist snd_soc_skl` in the config file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

As this fixed my issue, I do not know if other solutions work as well, but I'm sure they do :). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Edit **`/etc/default/grub`** as root and add the next kernel parameter:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
```

Save and then execute in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And restart...

The latest kernel update (5.3.0-42), while trying to fix things end up breaking them... This should fix it up again....

[Ubuntu 18.04 audio disappeared after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update)