# audio drivers are incorrect would like to restore to 'factory' settings

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

My mic stopped working recently. Trying to fix it made things worse. now I don't have audio. would like to at least go back to where the audio works. Here's my `lspci -v`

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 11) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2292
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at ea23c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ea000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev
```

originally I didn't have the `snd_soc_skl` nor the `sof_pci_dev`

how do I remove those drivers? and use the `snd_hda_intel`?

Comment: Just undo the changes you've made.

Comment: I would love to... how do I do that? @mikewhatever

Comment: Do it the same way you've made the changes, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: if you know how to find and remove the drivers listed above, please help. otherwise your comments are unhelpful. @mikewhatever

Comment: Those are kernel modules that get loaded, probably because of what you've done while trying to fix things. I don't know what you've done, so all I can tell is undo it. How is that unhelpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this post solved my questions... blacklisting the drivers, and setting the default restored my audio.

[Ubuntu 18.04 - Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon sound card not recognized since firmware update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218130/ubuntu-18-04-lenovo-thinkpad-carbon-sound-card-not-recognized-since-firmware-u)