# 19.10 multiple issues (e.g. sound, bluetooth) after lenovo firmware upgrade - thinkpad t490

Tags: sound, bluetooth, lenovo, 19.10, thinkpad

From the Ubuntu software app I clicked on Lenovo firmware upgrade. 
After a reboot I'm facing multiple issues:

1) sound not working. Settings->sound is on "dummy output" by default but even changing output device to "speakers" doesn't work. I tried `sudo alsa force-reload` but nothing changed.

```
x@y:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9dc8] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [17aa:2279]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, sof_pci_dev
```

2) Bluetooth headset (Bose QC-II) doesn't connect (via Bluetooth) to the PC anymore.

3) Each login (I'm using an external monitor), right after clicking on "login" the monitor losses signal from the laptop (I see a black screen saying "HDMI"), and then I'm back to the login screen. The second time, I always manage to login (even if the screen becomes first all purple and lags for a couple of seconds)

Comment: Looks like [this user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218130/ubuntu-18-04-lenovo-thinkpad-carbon-sound-card-not-recognized-since-firmware-u) had a similar problem, and the community was able to help them fix the dummy output problem. The bluetooth error was also reported by the user, but unfortunately not fixed. As for the HDMI issue, have you tried using the laptop's built-in screen without the external attached?

Comment: Thanks! With your suggestion I solved both the audio and Bluetooth issues. For the HDMI issue, with the build-in screen only the login works properly.

Comment: For reasons I don't understand, the audio and the Bluetooth work if and only if I log-in into Ubuntu with my external monitor disconnected. However, even if it works, the Bluetooth connection with my headset keeps disconnecting.