# I don't hear any sound on Kubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: sound

I have Kubuntu installed on an HP Omen and everything was fine until 2 events happened that I attribute may be due to the sound being completely gone.

The first was that a new update of the Nvidia 440 driver arrived from repository ppa: graphics-drivers / ppa

And the other event was that I wanted to install GLava in Kubuntu from a PPA but it could not be installed due to the lack of a library.

After that, I left the computer on, and when I came back there was no sound at all.
There is no sound from the speakers and also when connecting headphones

I Uninstalled and reinstalled pulseaudio and nothing

I think it is a problem with HDA Nvidia with PavuControl all the profiles appear unplugged.
I don't know how to fix it

Later I changed the nvidia driver to nouveau and it was worse because now only a black screen appears to log in and when logging in I access a terminal, I don't know what commands to use in case there are any to solve these problems.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, found a solution here on askubuntu and it worked for me! [Ubuntu 18.04 audio disappeared after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update/1218063?stw=2#1218063)

tomas reported that after adding a boot parameter to grub, their audio was restored. https://askubuntu.com/a/1218063/718497

> So to answer my own question. After a lot of digging I finally managed to get my audio working again. After finding this thread https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64720 I tried temporarily adding the boot parameter `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` by following this guide: [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter) to verify that it worked. It solved my problem, and I added the key permanently now, and the fix seems to persist after reboot.

Please upvote tomas if it helps. :-)

(I would've posted this as a comment, but my rep isn't 50 just yet)

Comment: Thank you very much Tristan, the sound is back

Comment: @nano Glad to  know that you  solved the issue. If you found this answer helpful, consider marking it as accepted answer by clicking ✅ on the left of the answer. Moreover, do consider deleting answers to other questions which are not really answers. For example, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218519/816190).

Answer (score 0):

If `sudo alsa force-reload` says no modules loaded, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

and then reboot. The kernel update script had a problem in some kernels around version 4.15.0-... Supposedly, it was fixed from kernel version 4.15.0-109 onward, but in my case 4.15.0-109 and 4.15.0-111 caused another problem, with expanding kernel and system logs till my disk was full. The above works best and gets you to the newest kernel supported for 18.04 LTS (there are similar packages for other LTS versions).