# Ubuntu 19.10 no sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hp

I have HP laptop. The sound disappeared after an update. I have tried [solution1](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/), [solution2](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/), [solution3](https://thetechhacker.com/2018/05/19/ubuntu-no-sound-fix/) , [solution4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218229/no-sound-dummy-output-ubuntu-19-10). Nothing works. Moreover, I cannot open alsamixer
"cannot open mixer: No such file or directory" I would really appreciate help. However, I am not an engineer so please keep it simple! Thank you!

Comment: Did you try this: pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload

Comment: yes. several times

Comment: @AkhileshSiddhanti

Comment: I have the same problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218218/i-dont-hear-any-sound-on-kubuntu-18-04-lts

Comment: @nano I am thinking of reinstalling ubuntu

Comment: The solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update/1218063#1218063

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 audio disappeared after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update)

Comment: FYI:  The duplicate link applies to 18.04 with HWE kernel, ie. same kernel & upper stack as 19.10

Comment: @guiverc unfortunately this did not solve the problem either

Comment: @guiverc I am not sure if this is the same thing but this worked: Open this file

sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

And then add the following line to it:

options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0

I rebooted et voila! Found it from: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

I did [this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/):
Open this file: `sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
And then add the following line to it: `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`
I saved it, rebooted and sound works! This seems to the same solution as many of you suggested but I just did not figure out where to add this line... Anyway, thanks for everyone!!!!

Comment: @Pilot6 just out curiosity, what does the -H do?

Comment: You can see it by `man sudo`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/632798/what-specific-bad-things-happen-when-gedit-is-used-with-sudo

Answer (score 1):

koppuli kappilka If you reinstall Ubuntu, don't install the Nvidia drivers because you will run out of sound again.
I did a clean installation of Kubuntu install the Nvidia drivers and I was left without sound again

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, found a solution here on askubuntu and it worked for me! [Ubuntu 18.04 audio disappeared after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update/1218063?stw=2#1218063)

tomas reported that after adding a boot parameter to grub, their audio was restored. https://askubuntu.com/a/1218063/718497

> So to answer my own question. After a lot of digging I finally managed to get my audio working again. After finding this thread https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64720 I tried temporarily adding the boot parameter `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` by following this guide: [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter) to verify that it worked. It solved my problem, and I added the key permanently now, and the fix seems to persist after reboot.

Please upvote tomas if it helps. :-)

(I would've posted this as a comment, but my rep isn't 50 just yet)

Comment: thank you! I will try that first thing tomorrow. Soundless social distancing is sad

Comment: this did not work

Comment: I think now I managed to do that , since the voice came back.