# Ubuntu 19.10 Dummy Output error

Tags: sound, 19.10

Dummy Output error for Ubuntu 19.10. Any idea how to fix it? The sound was lost at the last update. I use Acer Swift 3. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 19.10 no sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218372/ubuntu-19-10-no-sound)

Comment: ** (org.gnome.gedit:4347): WARNING **:...: Ser document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata:gedit-position not supported

Comment: This doesn't matter. I don't recommend using `sudo gedit`. At least `sudo -H gedit`, but it doesn't matter how you edit the file.

Comment: I tried the commands recommended there but I keep on getting "command not found". I am not an IT person, so I have no idea what to do to fix it. Could you give me the right syntax? I am using Acer Swift 3

Comment: Which command not found?

Comment: sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf; I found sometning with "inexi" (I thing, but after reboot, I couldn't remember on which page I found that.

Comment: You probably are not running Ubuntu. Instead of `gedit` you can use e.g. `nano`. It will open a text-based editor. Ctrl+O to save, Ctrl+X to exit.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 19.10; GNOME 3.34.2

Comment: You probably didn't understand. You run a command, an editor will open, then you edit the file.

Comment: Clearly, I am not for this :(. Thank you for taking the time to answer me. Any idea if this kind of issue is going to be solved with the next update?

Comment: You can boot with a previous kernel using grub menu. I think this will be fixed soon.

Comment: But the first time `gedit` started OK :-) see your first comment.

Comment: I have sound!!!It worked with: sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf;  Add the following line to the end of this file: options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0         https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persistent Dummy Output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800262/persistent-dummy-output)

Answer (score 2):

You [commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219889/ubuntu-19-10-dummy-output-error/1254489#comment2051810_1219889)

> I have sound!!! It worked with:
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
> ```
>
> Add the following line to the end of this file:
>
> ```
> options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
> ```
>
> [as suggested at] https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

(In systems [earlier than 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186999/how-does-sudo-handle-home-differently-since-19-10), you should use `sudo -H gedit` rather than `sudo gedit`)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove timidity
sudo reboot
```