# No Sound (Dummy Output) error Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 19.10

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 for few months. Suddenly voice output is not working. In-spite of trying reinstalling sound drives and tried all options despite that  it is not working. Any inputs to it?

Comment: I would boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media and use 'try ubuntu') to confirm it's not hardware (ideally I'd suggest using something rather different to what you have installed, but even a 19.10 'live' would be useful).  I've got a dying desktop that on rare occasions boots with 'dummy output' and in my case, it's components on their way to never working again (rebooting usually fixes it for me, but not always.. and it's the same for any booted OS whether installed or 'live')

Comment: I have the same problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218218/i-dont-hear-any-sound-on-kubuntu-18-04-lts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to Andrea Pavan's answer:

You can first add the variable to a new boot session and check if it works

1. Reboot your system. AT GRUB, choose Ubuntu and press `E`. You will be taken to command line options.
2. Locate the line beginning with `Linux`. Add the following parameter at the end of the line `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0`
3. Press `F10` to reboot.

After verifying this has indeed solved your sound issue, you can make this change permanently by performing the below steps

1. Run `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` from terminal.
2. Locate the line beginning with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and append the above parameter to it. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"`
3. Save and Close `gedit`.
4. Run `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
5. Reboot.

When I was stuck with the same issue, the below link helped me resolve it.

https://superuser.com/questions/1509312/sound-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-linux-5-4-intel-hd-audio?newreg=2fc5756bbf694e12b60ef3601f2e2411

Comment: Thanks Bhargav it worked

Comment: This works, but now there's no internal mic support, is there a way to make the mic work as well?

Answer (score 3):

For > 5.3.0-40 kernels, try adding:

"options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" in the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf.

and finally reboot the system. 
This worked for me!

Comment: Thanks Andrea...

Answer (score 0):

Sound works well with Kubuntu USB live.
The cause of no sound being heard from speakers or headphones is because
There is a problem with an error in the last update of the PPA with the Nvidia driver.
They sent a filth as update and they have not solved it.