# Sound disappeared

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.10, soundcard

I tried to play sound today, and no sound.

Similar questions and my failed attempts:

1. [No Sound (Dummy Output) error Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218398/no-sound-dummy-output-error-ubuntu-19-10) but no solution here
2. `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` changed nothing
   `pacmd list-cards` lists 0 cards.

also, typing `pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo` gives `No card found by this name or index.`

source: ["Dummy Output" No sound in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04)

3. Trying `sudo alsactl init 0`

gives 
`alsactl: init:1778: Cannot find soundcard '0'...`

source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/ubuntu-18-04-dummy-output-and-sound-disappeared-4175659386/

4. `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse` and then rebooting also fails
   source: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/
5. `sudo apt-get remove alsa-base pulseaudio`
   `sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio`

failed.  Source: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

6. sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils

sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils

sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` 
alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools 
alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui

sudo usermod -a -G audio username

sudo reboot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sound disappeared in Ubuntu 19.10, previous solutions not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218551/sound-disappeared-in-ubuntu-19-10-previous-solutions-not-working)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 audio disappeared after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update)

Comment: FYI: I know you're on 19.10, but it's impacting HWE kernel which is shared with 19.10