# No sound on Ubuntu 19.10. Dummy output

Tags: sound

All of a sudden there's this sound issue which shows **'Dummy Output'**.
Further in the `settings->sound` it is not able to detect any output device. I need to restart my PC every time to fix it. Kindly suggest what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Sound (Dummy Output) error Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218398/no-sound-dummy-output-error-ubuntu-19-10)