# No sound (dummy output) Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, 19.10

I just installed Ubuntu 19.10 and I have no sound at all. I know my hardware is working because I heard system sounds when I was booting from a USB to install Ubuntu. When I go to system sound settings all I can see is a dummy output, with no option to change it.

Some other relevant information:

- I cannot open alsamixer, even with sudo, it returns

"cannot open mixer: No such file or directory"

- Here is the output from 'sudo lspci -vv | grep -i audio'

"""00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"""

- Here is the output from "sudo dmesg | grep -i audio"

"[    0.416732] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    3.181791] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    3.210073] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: Unsupported HDAudio/iDisp configuration found"

- Only dummy output shows up in pavucontrol
- "cat /proc/asound/cards" produces

"--- no soundcards ---"

Outputs of uname -a, lspci and inxi are pasted below. If anyone would be able to me a hand with this that would be amazing. Apologies for any mistakes I am a linux newbie, just started using it for bioinformatics. If you need any other information that might help just give me a shout!

uname -a

Linux harry-HP-EliteBook-850-G6 5.3.0-42-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 05:49:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

inxi

CPU: Quad Core Intel Core i5-8365U (-MT MCP-) 
speed/min/max: 800/400/4100 MHz Kernel: 5.3.0-42-generic x86_64 Up: 21m 
Mem: 1580.9/31925.3 MiB (5.0%) Storage: 476.94 GiB (1.7% used) Procs: 268 
Shell: bash 5.0.3 inxi: 3.0.36

lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 11)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 11)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9de3 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9dbf (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM (rev 11)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
39:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
3a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
3b:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983

Comment: The answer here fixed this issue for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1218063/44768. I had been using Ubuntu 19.10 with sound correctly on my ThinkPad X1 Gen 7 no problem for months but suddenly after updating today I get no sound card detected and dummy output.

Comment: Thanks, that made some progress -I  still don't have microphone or speakers but my headphones now give sound and I can open alsamixer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Sound (Dummy Output) error Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218398/no-sound-dummy-output-error-ubuntu-19-10)

Answer (score 0):

A citation from [another site](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=307934):

```
sudo modprobe -v snd-hda-intel
sudo modprobe -v snd-soc-skl-hda-dsp
sudo modprobe -v snd-soc-skl
sudo alsa force-reload
```

This might solve your problem but I am not sure I can't confirm it.

Comment: I just tried that but no luck :(