# Sound and the microphone problem after upgrade

Tags: 18.04, sound, microphone

yesterday March 18th 2020, I made an Ubuntu update and both the sound and the microphone stopped working. I tried to perform a complete reinstallation, but nothing to do. Until the day before, everything worked properly.
Ubuntu 18.04 operating system.
Computers: Lenovo Yoga C930.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 audio disappeared after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update)

Answer (score 0):

It's a kernel bug > 5.3.0-40.

Add `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect = 0` in the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf.

After adding the line to the config file reboot works: the audio problem is solved, NOT the mic problems.....