# Ubuntu 18.04 without sound (dummy sound) and does not recognize mic (Nvidia)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, sound

I have a Dell notebook with Nvidia Geforce GTX 1660 TI running Ubuntu 18.04. When  I search for sound output, only the dummy output appears:

```
nvidia-smi
Thu Mar 19 12:04:22 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00    Driver Version: 440.64.00    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   53C    P8     2W /  N/A |    416MiB /  5944MiB |      8%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1093      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            28MiB |
|    0      1187      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          48MiB |
|    0      1509      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           181MiB |
|    0      1694      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          89MiB |
|    0      2051      G   ...AAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAA --shared-files    62MiB |
|    0      3052      G   gnome-control-center                           1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and

````
$ aplay -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions ```

I hope that someone could help me.
````

Comment: I had the same issue check this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218063/1055428)