# 18.04.04 sound card not detected after updates

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

this is the output of my lspci for Audio

```
sudo lspci | grep -i Audio

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

however when i do `aplay -l`

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
       Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Cant get my audio speakers to work, only headphone works as expected.

Any hint on what could be done ?

Comment: The solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update/1218063#1218063

Comment: The solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update/1218063#1218063

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 audio disappeared after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update)

Comment: Same answer of the fellow bellow. It worked as expected.