# No sound in ubuntu 18.04 showing Dummy output

Tags: 18.04, sound, alsa, soundcard

my ubuntu 18.04 was working fine..suddenly something went wrong and when i restarted my laptop.my ubuntu's sound was gone.Its now showing Dummy output. when i try *aplay -l* it shows

*aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...* i have tried many things even resetting alsa..but nothing is working..

also windows is working fine

Problem Solved.
link to the solution: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 audio disappeared after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update)