# Sound issues with intel audio on a laptop running 20.04

Tags: sound, laptop, microphone

I have audio issues in my Ubuntu 20.04, I think since the kernel upgraded to 5.4.0-40, from various questions here I added the boot param `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0`, but now, naturally, I have no microphone.
I tried to search for this issue in launchpad and didn't find anything relevant, though I got many outdated and irrelevant results, so I don't even know if the problem is being worked on and what stage it's at.
I tried the workaround in the comments to [Ubuntu 18.04 audio disappeared after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update/1218063) and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fixed in 5.4.0-52